# Parse SVG path style using Batik

Tags: svg, java-2d, batik

Using Batik, I am converting some SVG code to direct Java/Scala code using Java2D commands. For example, I have the following fragment:

```
<path
  id="path3622"
  transform="translate(0,152.36218)"
  d="m 720,94.5625 c -190.64053,0 -346.23512,150.07433 -355.0625,338.53125 235.63168,-82.12984 472.1202,-97.44221 710.0313,-1.78125 C 1065.2448,243.69491 910.03743,94.5625 720,94.5625 z"
  style="opacity:0.28999999;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none"
/>
```

I have already solved the `d=` bit, using a `PathHandler` to produce the correct `GeneralPath2D`. How would I go about parsing the `transform` and the `style` attributes? The `transform` I can imagine I can manage myself by hand, but for the style, it would be great to have **a parser that gives me direct access to the fill and stroke values**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Batik has very clumsy API and I also had to struggle with it. This is how I approached a similar problem.

```
import org.apache.batik.anim.dom.SVGStylableElement;

private void fill(SVGStylableElement element, String fillValue) {
    element.getStyle().setProperty("fill", fillValue, "");
}
```

Usage is pretty obvious. First parameter is an instance of a `SVGStylableElement` (see below). Second is the color value that you want to set (e.g. "#FF0000"). Note that `setProperty()` has also third parameter - it's can be used to set `!important` in CSS (I didn't need it).

So first you need to get an instance of `SVGStylableElement`.

```
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.svg.SVGDocument;

private Optional<SVGStylableElement> getElement(final SVGDocument svg, String id) {
    Element element = svg.getElementById(id);
    if (null == element) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    if (!SVGStylableElement.class.isAssignableFrom(element.getClass())) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    return Optional.of((SVGStylableElement) element);
}
```

The method above is in Java8+ style but can be re-written for older Java version if needed. You provide an instance of `SVGDocument` and element id (in your example that would be "path3622").

I assume that you already have an instance of `SVGDocument` created somehow so I omit it here.
The last but required method is initialization of CSS Engine. This is kind of Batik's magic. You can find more info there https://wiki.apache.org/xmlgraphics-batik/BootSvgAndCssDom

```
import org.apache.batik.bridge.BridgeContext;
import org.apache.batik.bridge.DocumentLoader;
import org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder;
import org.apache.batik.bridge.UserAgentAdapter;

private void initializeEngine(SVGDocument svg) {
    UserAgentAdapter userAgent = new UserAgentAdapter();
    DocumentLoader loader = new DocumentLoader(userAgent);
    BridgeContext ctx = new BridgeContext(userAgent, loader);
    ctx.setDynamicState(BridgeContext.DYNAMIC);
    GVTBuilder builder = new GVTBuilder();
    builder.build(ctx, svg);
}
```

So remember to call this `initializeEngine(...)` method **once** just after you created instance of `SVGDocument`. If you don't do this, you get NPE in `element.getStyle()` in `fill(...)` method.

Just for reference, these are entries in my pom.xml that I used:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
    <artifactId>batik-svg-dom</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
    <artifactId>batik-anim</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
    <artifactId>batik-bridge</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

How about javascript?

```
  var pathFill=path3622.style.fill
  var pathStroke=path3622.style.stroke
```

Comment: And how would I do that with the Batik API from Java or Scala? And how would I get data structures back from JS?

Comment: It looks like you can index thru the style in java as:  String style = el.getAttribute("style");
             int index1 = style.indexOf("fill:#");